# SoundPool repeating issue for Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm trying to play a background sound for my application, I use `SoundPool` class, my problem is that, sound plays well only when I set the ***loop*** parameter with zero value, but it doesn't work for any other value.

My code for initialization is:

```
    soundpool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    soundsMap.put(1, soundpool.load(this, R.raw.soundfile_1, 1));
    soundsMap.put(2, soundpool.load(this, R.raw.soundfile_2, 1));
```

my code for playing is

```
 soundpool.play(1,  0.9f, 0.9f, 1, -1, 1f);
```

as I mentioned sound works when I put (0) instead of (-1) for the loop value, anyone has any idea why (-1) or any value other than (0) doesn't work (there is no output sound) ?

Comment: Do you have similar errors in the log as mentioned here: http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-development-answers-tutorials-code-snippets/5132-soundpool-setloop-possible-bug.html You may have bigger samples than the (invisible) limit allows.

Comment: my audio file rate is 1411 kbps, is that what you mean ?

Comment: No, I mean the size of the sound files. Bigger files with more frames might exceed some undocumented maximum frame count limit and stay silent. If you have only really short sounds then this probably isn't the case.

Comment: My file size is 2.7 MB, what is the limit you're talking about ?

Comment: SoundPool may have some internal size limit which kicks in when you're looping. What that limit is, is have no idea. Certainly 2.7 MB sounds like quite a big file for SoundPool to handle since it's mostly meant for playing short sound clips.

Comment: you can put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file size is probably too big for looping as has been reported here: http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-development-answers-tutorials-code-snippets/5132-soundpool-setloop-possible-bug.html

The file size seems pretty big for SoundPool in general, so maybe the sound clip should be cut into smaller clips and/or MediaPlayer used.